# Excel - Working out an overall Percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to create a table in Excel which works out the overall average performance of a driver.

The layout of the table is below. You can see if the driver has had drops and has no early, late and OTIF then the total should show 100%.

[image]

But if the driver was to get an Early (for example) then this will affect the total percentage (it should go down from 100% to 90% for example). But i'm unsure on what formula to use in Excel? Any help / or tips would be very helpful!

Thank you.

Comment: could you give examples of when the percentage is less than 100 and what that percentage would be?

Comment: So each one drops it by 10%?

Comment: No, it should go off the number of drops that driver had. So if the driver had 50 drops and 1 Early, then it will affect him more compared to a driver with 100 drops and 1 Early. if thats understandable ?

Comment: no it is not, we do not know the rules and relationships.  Therefor, we cannot possibly help with a formula.  You have to explain the rules, how they relate and what weight to give to certain items.

Comment: in your statement you say: driver has had drops : Yet your example shows 0 for drops.  You need to reword your question better and listen to @ScottCraner about what is needed to assist you.

Comment: @dwirony with the first three as 0, and E4 > 0, as I understand, should return 100% and your formula would be 0.  Again as I understand, and I am still not sure, `(E4-(B4+C4+D4))/E4`

Comment: @ScottCraner Oops you're right - I spaced out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am taking a guess here that the formula you want is:

```
=IFERROR((E4-(B4+C4+D4))/E4,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarity is needed on whether the Early, Late or OTIF numbers decrease the percentage by a fixed 10% each, or if it is just a percentage of the successful drops.

To find that number, the easiest way to do this is the following.  *(Note: I am assuming that the Drops column is indicating the total number of drops and not just the number of successful drops)*

The best way to do this would be to take the total number of drops and subtract the number of undesirable outcomes from it. This creates the number of successful drops. Once that number is created, a simple division by the total number of drops will create the proper percentage. *see below formula*

```
=((E5-E2-E3-E4)/E4)
```

This should take the total number of successful drops and divide it by the total number of drops.

Hopefully, this helped! Good luck!